# they won’t get a Covid-19 vaccine

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "won’t get a Covid-19 vaccine" mean "will not (want to) get a Covid-19 vaccine"?

Why this thread? "Won't get" or "will not get" appears to have a meaning that you fail or are able to get one you need rather than showing your unwillingness to accept the vaccine into your arm."  I am not sure.

> New England Journal of Medicine tweeted:

> About 27% of Americans say **they definitely or probably won’t get a Covid-19 vaccine**, even if it’s free and deemed safe by scientists. The behavioral obstacles to widespread vaccination are thus as important to understand as the scientific and logistic hurdles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that they are not willing to take the vaccine.

On its own, "won’t get a Covid-19 vaccine" could mean that (1) they are unwilling to take the vaccine (i.e., they are skeptical and do not trust the government, scientists, process, producers, products, etc.) or that (2) they are not eligible for the vaccine (i.e., may be due to preexisting health conditions or because they are temporary foreign workers or international students).

But the context seems to indicate that it is the first reason.

> The **behavioral** obstacles to widespread vaccination ...

Answer (score 2):

"Will not get" merely means that you will not receive it, whether it's from your own choice or external forces.

Comment: I think this is the more accurate answer. In some countries, depending on availability, there may be substantial numbers of people who "won't get a vaccine" because it isn't available at all. In other countries, where the vaccine is freely available, it then becomes a matter of choice. The phrase in the question title is neutral. Once you look at the quoted passage (referring to Americans) then it looks more like it is a matter of choice.